# How to optimally compare if element is in a list of ranges?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, performance

I have two 2D lists with one million+ entries. `List1` is full of ranges (e.g. `[100, 25]` meaning the range starts at `100` and has a span of `25`, or `100` to `125`) and `List2` is full of plot points. I have to count how many ranges each point fits into.

Since I'm dealing with such a large amount of data, I began with a binary search function to make searching for a starting point easier, rather than cycling through the whole list one by one. Except I've modified the search to return the closest index from `List1` that is ABOVE my plot point, because the plot point is not guaranteed to be an element in `List1`.

I end up doing a comparison between each plot point in `List2` and `List1`, starting at the index I got from the Binary Search, moving downwards in `List1` until  the plot point is no longer within a range. Although this works, this is very time consuming and inefficient.

```
def findRange(List1, List2):

    for plot in List2:
        count = 0
        startIndex = binarySearch(List1, plot)

        while plot <= List1[startIndex - 1][0] + 250:
            if List1[startIndex][0] < plot[0] < List1[startIndex][0] + List1[startIndex][1]:
                count += 1
            startIndex -= 1

        plot[1] = count
    return List2
```

I have the `... + 250` in the `while` loop because the range distance can be anywhere from `0` to `250`, so I use that to determine whether or not further indices might contain the point.

I've looked at converting `List1` into a dictionary where the key is the summed distance, and the value is the number of repeats found. I thought that by getting rid of repeating ranges, I could cut back on some of the overhead. I couldn't find a way to get the correct solution this way though.

Is there any suggestions you can direct me in to better optimize my algorithm? I can only use the standard library.

EDIT:

```
List1 = [
    [1233, 120],
    [1233, 80],
    [1490, 50],
    [1789, 220],
    [1800, 250]
]
 
List2 = [
    [1300, 0], 
    [1450, 0], 
    [1490, 0], 
    [2000, 0]
]
```

I am supposed to update the zeros in `List2` with the count of how many ranges the plot point falls into. So an output would be something like this:

```
List2 = [
    [1300, 2], # this point can be found in List1[0] and List1[1] because 1300 is between 1233-1353 and 1233-1313
    [1450, 0], # this plot can be found in none of ranges
    [1490, 1], # this plot can be found in List1[2] 
    [2000, 2]  # this plot can be found in List1[2] and List1[3]
]
```

As you can see, the count index is updated in `List2` from 0 to the number of ranges contains the point.

Comment: This makes my head hurt.  Can you provide a short sample of your List1 and List2?  Also, it would be helpful if you could establish the output that would result from this sample input.

Comment: Rather than put this in a comment which is hard to read, please update your question and format this so that it is easy to read.

Comment: Also, when you say "I'm supposed to update that count with the count of how many ranges..."  Be explicit about what 'that' is and what 'ranges' you are referencing.

Comment: I see, I hope that clarified what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1 (Binary Search)**

You may be better off searching in `List2` for the elements of `List1` instead of the other way around. Assuming both lists are sorted, you are always going to be shrinking your search space. Also, you will avoid the potentially wasteful operation you must do in assuming an upper bound on range size.

As a side note, binary search is implemented in python in the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module. I recommend using both [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) (for range starts) and [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) for range ends.

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

start = 0
for rnge in List1:
    start = bisect_left(List2, [rnge[0], 0], start)
    end = bisect_right(List2, [rnge[0] + rnge[1] - 1, 0], start)
    for plot_index in range(start, end):
        List2[plot_index][1] += 1
```

The result for your example is

```
>>> List2
[[1300, 2], [1450, 0], [1490, 1], [2000, 2]]
```

**Version 2 (One-pass Linear Search)**

All that being said, a better solution comes to mind. You can do the whole operation in a single pass over both lists at the same time. There are two ideas that go into making this happen.

First, consider what happens if you have two iterators that you can peek into. You can always check which one is larger and which one is smaller and increment the appropriate one until the head of the other one is larger or smaller.

Secondly, you can take List1, convert both the start and end of each range into an index, and sort all those indices. However, you still have to keep track of which indices represent entering a range and which ones represent exiting a range. In fact, you can imagine that entering a range increments the number that should be assigned to all plots you encounter in it, while exiting a range decrements that number.

Let's begin by transforming `List1` using the second idea. It will become a list of pairs, where the first element is an index, and the second is either +1 or -1 depending on whether the index is a start or end:

```
actions = []
for rnge in List1:
    actions.append([rnge[0], +1])
    actions.append([rnge[0] + rnge[1], -1])
actions.sort()
```

Now you can step along both lists (`action` and `List2`), keeping tack of the running sum of the increments from `action`. If the element from `List2` has a smaller key than the one from `action`, you assign the current increment to the one from `List2` and move on. If the one from `action` has a smaller or equal key, you process it by updating the increment (i.e., entering or exiting a range):

```
end = (List2[-1] + 1, 0) # Key to ensure that increment stops changing once actions runs out
it = iter(actions)
key, inc = next(it, end)
increment = 0
for plot in List2: # Keep plot as a list, since it needs to be incremented
    while key <= plot[0]:
        increment += inc
        key, inc = next(it, end)
    plot[1] += increment
```

While this approach has two parts, notice that it only makes two linear passes along `List1` and one pass along `List2`. There is no actual searching involved, only comparison. The call `next(it, end)` ensures that all of `List2` gets processed completely no matter what by not incrementing `iterator` once `actions` has run out.

As before, the result is

```
>>> List2
[[1300, 2], [1450, 0], [1490, 1], [2000, 2]]
```